# Camera overlay stays closed after navigation

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working with an application that has three screens.

At first is the home screen. From the home screen with a button the user navigates to the second screen where I have a camera overlay with only a button to take picture.

When the user takes a picture then he can press a button that navigates to the last screen. But when he navigates from the last screen to the home and then goes to the overlay-second screen the camera is closed. The button appears he can take a picture but he cannot see through the camera.

I use the following code to the home screen to initiate the overlay:

```
if (self.imageView.isAnimating)
    self.imageView.stopAnimating;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType])
{
    [self.overlayViewController setupImagePicker:sourceType];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];
}
```

Where `overlayviewcontroller` is the second screen and at the `overlayviewcontroller` the following code:

```
- (void)setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

        if ([[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView subviews] count] == 0)
        {
            CGRect overlayViewFrame = self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                         CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame) - self.view.frame.size.height - 10.0,
                                         CGRectGetWidth(overlayViewFrame),
                                         self.view.frame.size.height + 10.0);
            self.view.frame = newFrame;
            [self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem is faced by me and I got one solution to it.

My solution is as below

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setCameraOverlayView) withObject:Nil afterDelay:2];
```

instead of directly putting the below line

```
[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
```

in `overlayViewController`'s above method

and put that line in the selector method `setCameraOverlayView`.

just like below

```
-(void)setCameraOverlayView
{
    [imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
}
```

This will solve your problem

Happy Coding :)

**EDIT**

To init the overlay I use the below code and the init function in overlay is also modified

**To init the overlay**

```
self.overlayViewController = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OverlayViewController" bundle:nil images:self.finalData];
```

**The init function in overlay**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil images:(NSArray *)imgArray
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]))
    {
        subCategories = imgArray;
        imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        imagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

The array is not required or necessary it is some extra info which I required to do some more with overlay you can omit it.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your suggestions. The problem though is that this code did not solve the problem. The overlay has the camera and the take picture button on the bottom.  It has as a result that the take picture button is displayed with delay 2 seconds but after the navigation the camera is still closed.The user can take a picture but  cannot see through the camera what picture is he taking of . I was wondering if you could suggest one solution to the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: ok have solved it before can give you solution too. But need some time

Comment: I think you need to dealloc the imagePickerController after taking image and allocate again on navigation to the imagePicker page for taking image. This seems to the memory related issue. Need to free some resources and when you need to take picture at that time you have to alloc the imagePickerController just before line and must have to dealloc it after taking picture